# NullReferenceException when validating Migration Summary

Tags: opshub

I am trying to migrate a Team Project from TFS 2015 to Visual Studio Team Services.  I connected to both the Source and Destination, selected the Team Project, mapped my users, and then when validating the Migration Summary a NullReferenceException is thrown.

The following was found in the OVSMU.log file:

> 2016-07-29 10:33:20,674 [1] ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.MigrationSummeryViewModel.worker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in c:\Project_CheckOut\TFSMigration\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\MigrationSummeryViewModel.cs:line 1096
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Has anyone seen a similar problem?

Comment: Hi, what is the exact version of OVSMU, and the update of TFS 2015 at your end?

Comment: I am using OVSMU v2.2.5.003 and TFS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Additionally, I have also tried to target a different VSTS tenant, but receive a failure when trying to enumerate the Team Projects:  TF26193: The team project <name> does not exist.  Check the team project name and try again.  The problem, however, is that the Team Project <name> doesn't exist in my VSTS account.

Comment: Hi, did you previously have OVSMU installed? And then a new version was installed as a replacement?

Comment: No, OVSMU was not previously installed.

Comment: Hi, can you share the entire set of logs to ovsmu@opshub.com. We'll need more information to debug this issue

Comment: Hi, can you also check one more thing? What is the collection name as per Web UI? And what is the collection name seen on the End Point Selection pop-up? Are they different, collection name ideally should be instance name (as per recent MS update)

Comment: Which endpoint are you asking for?  The Source Endpoint or the Destination Endpoint?  Our TFS Collection name (Source) does not map to the VSTS Instance name (Destination).  For example, I am trying to migrate from tfs.kizan.com/tfs/KiZAN to my personal VSTS account (davidbuckingham.visualstudio.com).  Or even a co-workers VSTS account.